# How to know whether a URL request for my website is from browser or from a automated program

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, httprequest, html, spam-prevention

My requirement is to know whether a request to my webpage is a genuine request (through browser ) or a automated request that is generated through some Java program. Where can I differentiate the request type?

Actually I need to block all the requests that are generated from program hence searching for the difference.

Comment: you can check for user-agent, or can design your page to send hidden parameter from page. Though both can be simulated even from automated-program.

Comment: Better minds than yours or mine (e.g. Google & YouTube) have failed to implement this.  What makes you think you can?

Comment: @ay89: as iam beginner can you tell me what is actually user-agent and how to check that in java code

Comment: Yes, you can check for user-agent, but it can _very_ easily be faked, so it should _not_ be the only detection you do.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: User-agent is a header field, which is sent along with the request object, basically to identify what browser/tool you are using for response rendering, so that response can be formatted accordingly, e.g. same URL can give different page for a OperaMini or FireFox.
on how to use it in java, see this - http://jawe.net/2006/07/23/setting-the-http-user-agent-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fool proof way of doing this.
The most effective solution for me was:

1. Implement a User Agent check at the web server level (Yes this is not fool proof). Target to block out the known / common programs that people use to hit URLs. Like libperl, httpclient etc. You should be able to build such a list from your access logs.
2. Depending on your situation, you may or may not want search engine spiders to crawl your site. Add robots.txt to your server accordingly. Not all spiders / crawlers follow instructions from robots.txt, but most do.
3. Use a specialized tool to detect abnormal access to your site. Something like https://www.cloudflare.com/ which can track all access to your site, and match it with an ever growing database of known and suspected bots.

Note: I am in no way affiliated to cloudflare :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no 100%, fool proof solution to this. Many suggest using the `User-Agent` header, but it can very easily be faked. And you can add an IP-filter, when you (probably manually) detect fake clients. But it'll just be a cat and mouse game. If you want to restrict access to your website, maybe you're better off building in some real authorization?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the "User-Agent" header and compare it to the most common ones (http://www.user-agents.org/)! Something like that:

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent").contains(...)
```

Comment: It's extremely easy to fake that header, so it can't be relied on.

Comment: Well, then i guess there is nothing else you can do!

Comment: @Constantin Hey then how it comes when i want to add all browsers User-Agents because we can't expect the request from only one browser naa

Answer (score -1):

You can check for user agent. Search for java user agent detection.